# VS2010 SP1 Variable Inspection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have a project in C#/.NET4 in which there are several nested loops within a method.  Recently, I have noticed that I can't mouseover to inspect variable values within these loops.  In fact, if I go to the immediate window and try to research the value manually, the compiler reports that the variable doesn't exist.  When I mouseover nothing appears, but its only at certain parts of one method.  If I look in other parts of the same code (I haven't been able to figure out what the difference between the parts is in terms of debugging) mouseover works fine.  I have things as simple as:

```
for (int i = 0...)
{
   XX Breakpoint is hit here XX
}
```

and I can't get the value of i!  Is there some limitation of the VS2010 debugger that is a known issue where it would affect only certain sections of code?  I deleted all my PDB files, completely rebuilt the files from scratch, and still it doesn't seem to know the variable exists.  Any advice is greatly appreciated on this one.

Comment: Have you done anything recently with your optimizations or build configuration (debug vs release)?

Comment: No, it's only in one very large method that it occurs so I think there is a limitation in the debugger that I can't find any mention of.

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think is when the breakpoint is hit, could you be actually inside a different (possibly anonymous) method?